# Introduction to holomorphic symplectic manifolds

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry

What is a good resource to learn basics about holomorphic symplectic manifolds? All references in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold#References) are concerned with *real* symplectic manifolds, and I'm not sure which basic results carry over to the case of complex manifolds. Thus I would like to have a reference which handles the complex case explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question whether you are interested in the case where the symplectic form is required to be holomorphic, or just where the underlying manifold is complex. The latter goes under the name of *Kähler geometry*, and you can find a chapter on this for instance in da Silva's *Lectures on Symplectic Geometry*. The former is often studied under the name of *hyperKähler geometry*: a nice introduction is *HyperKähler Manifolds* by Hitchin.